# Question about non differentiability function in pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a problem with neural networks that predicts.

```
y_predicted = self.net(x)
z_predicted = self.calculate_z(y_predicted)
```

I would like to minimise the loss in prediction in both y and z. However, the method self.calculate_z is non-deterministic and used by a simulation. Is there any way to include the loss between z_predicted and z_real in pytorch?

Above an example of what I want to do: (x input, y_real (real target 1), z_real (real target 2), self.net (neural network))

```
def example(self, x, y_real, z_real):
    y_predicted = self.net(x)
    z_predicted = self.calculate_z(y_predicted)
    self.loss = self.criterionL1(z_predicted, z_real) + self.criterionL1(y_real, y_predicted)
    self.loss.backward()
```

Comment: It all depends on what you mean by "non-deterministic"? Can you explicit this? Are you training a GAN?

Answer (score 0):

CUDA and cudnn is partly non deterministic. Non determinism is not the problem it has to be differentiable. So whatever `self.calculate_z` does, it has to work the autograd in pytorch. So basically using tensors and pytorch tensor operations.

It really depends on what the simulation does, how complicated it is. Does it change or should it change during training? If `self.calculate_z` is not differentiable, you have to keep it out of the loss. There needs to be a path in the computation graph from `z_predicted` to your network.

Also including a loss for `z` only seems to make sense when there are learnable parameters in `self.calculate_z` otherwise it can be seen as "constant" and you network only predicts `y` anyway and `z` is directly dependent on the `y`. So setting a loss for `y`is sufficient.